# model data disappears between controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So i have a model with two models in it so that i can render to different views on the same view, one login view and one register view.

This is my model:

```
public class SignUpLoginModel
{
    public LoginModel loginmodel { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel registermodel { get; set; }
}
```

And when i am trying to register a new user with this controller method:

```
  public ActionResult Register(SignUpLoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.registermodel.UserName,
                    model.registermodel.Password,
                    new
                    {
                        FirstName = model.registermodel.Firstname,
                        LastName = model.registermodel.Lastname,
                        Country = model.registermodel.Country,
                        City = model.registermodel.City,
                        Birthdate = model.registermodel.Birthdate
                    });

                WebSecurity.Login(model.registermodel.UserName, model.registermodel.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return RedirectToAction("Register", "Home", model);
    }
```

So the modelstate.isvalid failes as it should and it redirects to the home controller and the register method and send the model. Here everything works fine, the model contains the data. But when i redirect to another controller

```
     public ActionResult Register(SignUpLoginModel model) 
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "RegisterFail";
        return View("Index", "Home", model);
    }
```

my model ends up with null instead of the right data. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a Post?  I would guess that SignupModel is null before Register is invoked.  Can you make sure your View is populating the model?  Perhaps show us the View?

Comment: What do you mean byt signupmodel is null before register is invoked?
It is only one of the models that is populated. First case the user already have a account and the user loggs in so then the loginmodel will be populated, and on the other case the user don't have an account so i wants to singup so then the registermodel will be populated and not the loginmodel.

Comment: Sorry maybe I don't understand enough about this approach.  I'm guessing the problem might be within the View, but I usually stick to simpler models so others here might be able to understand better.

Comment: I can edit my question and add the view. It is a popup approach, thats why it is a little bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) (neither the overload you are using nor any of the other signatures) doesn't forward your model for you. It sends a 302 back to your browser which then issues a new GET request to a new url - therefore your model data is lost.

So you'd need to do something like this in the first controller

```
{
   TempData["signupModel"]=model;       
   return RedirectToAction("Register", "Home", model);       
}
```

and then this in the redirect controller:

```
public ActionResult Register(SignUpLoginModel model) 
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "RegisterFail";
        return View("Index", "Home", TempData["signupModel"]);
    }
```

But what I don't understand is why you don't just directly return a view the first time around, why do you need to redirect - because from your code you seem to be just redirecting back to the same controller -  or  have I missed something?

### Edit based on comments below

I honestly think you would be better off using Ajax for this because what you're trying to do here is maintain state across multiple controllers/views which is not really idiomatic for MVC.

If you submit the "register" popup form via Ajax, then you never actually leave the Index page, you just execute some code server-side and return some JSON to indicate if your registration was OK or not. When this response indicates an error you can just display an error message on the popup form or whatever, otherwise you can redirect to wherever on the client-side.

OR

When your `Register` controller decides that registration has failed, return the Home page index view e.g

```
ViewBag.Message = "RegisterFail";
return View("~/HomePage/HomeController/Index.cshtml", model); //or whatever the virtual path to the home page view is
```

However I don't like this approach as it sounds to me like you have your register form HTML being generated in-line by the the Home page view, which sounds like mixed concerns to me.

Comment: Now i get the right data, but it goes to my dispose method:

 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_db != null)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

And then it says it can't find the view: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: But are you redirecting to the same controller, or a totally different controller - it's not clear from your original post. If you;re redirecting to the *same* controller, there's no point - just return the View directly, if its a different controller, then are you 100% certain you have a view called Index.cshtml in the right location for that controller?

Comment: Im using home/index view and that renders a popup loginform but if the user wants to signup it presses signup and it swiches to another popup with the registerform and when they submit the form they go to account/register to try to register the form. if they fail i want it to render home/index again but show the registerform-popup istead. Thats why i try to redirect it to home/index and send a viewbag message to split it from rendering the loginform and instead render the registerform directly